# Javascript SetTimeout Function Not Pausing After Execution

Tags: javascript, css, web

I am checking for a change in a CSS class. I want the check to happen every 1000 milliseconds. Currently in the Google Chrome console, I can see it checking without any delay, causing the webpage to crash. What is the issue with the below setTimeout function? Perhaps there is another way of checking for a change in a CSS class also?

```
var itemInfo = null;

itemInfo = document.getElementById('option-item-info');
while (itemInfo.className == "disabled") {
    console.log("Test 1");
    getOptionItemInfo();
}

function getOptionItemInfo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Checking...");
        itemInfo = document.getElementById('option-item-info');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `while` loop isn't going to wait for the `setTimeout` async callback, it's just going to trigger tons of `setTimeouts` until your browser crashes. Instead, just kick off the `setTimeout` once and then only call it again from within the callback if you haven't met the desired condition.

```
getOptionItemInfo();

function getOptionItemInfo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Checking...");
        var itemInfo = document.getElementById('option-item-info');
        if (itemInfo.className == "disabled") {
            getOptionItemInfo(); 
        } else {
            console.log("done!");
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```